# Selenium clicking on a div(Java) - GmailRegister

Tags: java, selenium, click

Trying to select Gender in Gmail registration page.. Clicking on Gender is opening a DIV with 3 options.. I was able to find the options using xpath and also capture the text or tagname.. but, click is not working

```
baseURL = "http://www.gmail.com";
driver.get(baseURL);
driver.findElement(By.id("link-signup")).click();

driver.findElement(By.id("Gender")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='Gender']//div[@class='goog-menu goog-menu-vertical']//div[@id=':e']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Gender in Gmail registration page is a dropdown. So, you need to wrap your WebElement into Select object and then select its option.

Following code may help you.

```
//Identify dropdown 

    Select gen= new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("Gender")));
```

//select its option.

```
gen.selectByVisibleText("Male");//provide value that you want to select here.
```

OR

```
gen.selectByIndex(1); // provide value's id here.
```

OR

```
gen.selectByValue("Ma");//provide value here.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.. Select is not working since the the options are in <div>                                                                                                 Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("Gender")));
  sel.selectByIndex(1);                                                                                     Error: Element should have been "select" but was "div"